# Laravel 5.3 using multiple authentication (e.g admin, customer)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have read a lot of threads about multi-auth in Laravel, most of the configurations I see are somehow complicated,  I have also seen a multi-auth package but it does not support Laravel Socialite. 
I am aware that this question is asked multiple times, but if someone can give a better answer. It would be much appreciated!

### Things I have tried

1. I am familiar with Laravel make:auth
2. I am also familiar with Laravel socialite Facebook , Twitter , Google plus.

Comment: Did you mean your website uses role based authentication?

Comment: I am not aware of what a role based authentication is. But the website i am building is an e commerce site, and of course with an admin dashboard for the admin which can only be accessed obviously by the admin. @BalrajAllam

Comment: Take a look at this github repo, may help you.https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate

Comment: You do not necessarily need multi auth. You could have one auth. User roles and then a set of routes and services that are only accessible to some user using a combination of middleware and the Gate facade.

Comment: @Wistar Then i'd have to alter my database design right? Which is something i am avoiding, i have read threads that suggests the same, like for example, the `users` table will have the common attributes between the `admin` and `customer`, which is for example, the `email` and `password`, the admin/customer table will have their unique attributes and a foreign key referencing the user id. But i want to simply to it with the admin and customer table.

Comment: @RalpawTato You can do that with only one table: the `users` table. Nothing prevents you to add a column `role` to your user table and then say "admin", "customer" or "1", "2". Alternatively, you could have `admin` and `customer` columns in your `users` table and make them boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. But you still need some basic knowledge about Laravel's new multitenancy.

1. In config/auth.php add something like this to `guards` array:

   ```
   'customer' => [
       'driver' => 'session',
       'provider' => 'customers',
   ],
   ```
2. Than in the same file add this to `providers` array:

   ```
       'customers' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Customer::class,
       ],
   ```
3. Than create Migration for `customers DB table` (you can use Laravel's out of the box migration for users table)
4. Next is Eloquent model `App\Customer` with these included:

   ```
   use App\Scopes\AuthorizedScope;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
   ```

These should let you use Laravel's Auth facade in your app with these most used methods:

```
    Auth::guard('customer')->attempt()
    Auth::guard('customer')->check()
    Auth::guard('customer')->logout()
    Auth::guard('customer')->user()
```

Or use auth middleware like this:

```
    Route::get('customer/dashboard', function () {
        // Only authenticated users may enter...
    })->middleware('auth:customer');
```

Also checkout these:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Do you think this would work with Laravel socialite? Because i am going to implement Laravel socialite on my customers.

Comment: Anyway i'll give this a try later and mark this as an answer if it does work.

Comment: Well it depends on your implementation. If you use Socialite to check for social connections, you should probably use some extra logic to connect social accounts with your app users.

Comment: In my login form, what would be the action that i would use?

Comment: maybe to do some checks and updates in auth middleware?